# How to get Ubuntu ufw or iptables to allow quake3-server to be seen by internet

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have ufw enabled. The Quake3 server service is named "quake3-server.service" and uses UDP port only. I have set iptables rules using:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport quake3-server -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27960 -j ACCEPT
```

and tried tcp settings as well. I have checked that those settings were applied and restarted iptables using:

```
systemctl stop    netfilter-persistent
systemctl start   netfilter-persistent
systemctl restart netfilter-persistent
```

I have tried adding the rule to ufw by:

```
sudo ufw allow 27960
sudo ufw allow 27960/udp
```

and tried adding the service And server:

```
sudo ufw allow quake3-server
sudo ufw allow quake3-server.service
```

and also added an "app profile" in etc/ufw/applications.d:

```
[quake3-server.service]
 title=Q3Server
 description=Q3 server details description
 ports=29760/udp|29760/tcp

[quake3-server]
 title=Q3Server
 description=Q3 server details description
 ports=29760/udp|29760/tcp
```

and successfully saving and restarting each addition.

The server's `sudo iptables -L` is as follows:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27960
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27960
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27960
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27960
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0              tcp dpt:27960
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0              udp dpt:27960
```

`ufw status verbose` shows:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
10000/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
27960/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
27960/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
27960                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
0.0.0.0 27960              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
10000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
27960/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
27960/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
27960 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

and `sudo ufw show raw` shows:

```
Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:10000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:27960


Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     897    53696 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
      23     1072 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       5      248 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
       1       44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0              tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0              udp dpt:27960

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   51529  4804279 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   51529  4804279 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12265   732225 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12037   719561 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12037   719561 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12037   719561 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960
```

ZenMap shows:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE

22/tcp    open  ssh

80/tcp    open  http

443/tcp   open  https

10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

and telnet doesn't seem to want to connect to port 27960 either.

So trying to get port 27960 viewable and connectable by the net.

A hint might be: that when disabling `ufw`, the port remained hidden still from the net in ZenMap and Telnet.

Upon downloading quake3-server I thought it would automatically add a firewall exception for the dedicated server but this doesn't seem to be the case, as `ufw app list` shows:

```
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  Bind9
  Dovecot IMAP
  Dovecot POP3
  Dovecot Secure IMAP
  Dovecot Secure POP3
  OpenSSH
  Postfix
  Postfix SMTPS
  Postfix Submission
```

It now shows `quake3-server.service` in that list as well necause I manually added it and restarted the both ufw and iptables services.

Any suggestions? Thanks. I'm sure it's something simple.

UPDATE

Results from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` per Doug Smythies:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 9716 packets, 434587 bytes)
        pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               dest ination
      206710 24244632 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
      206710 24244632 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
       23145  1226262 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
       21753  1154148 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
       21753  1154148 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
       21753  1154148 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0 
 0.0.0.0/0
           0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
           0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960


Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               dest ination
   12517   741629 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
     201    10072 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
     146     7628 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
      26     1200 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0              tcp dpt:27960
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0              udp dpt:27960
```

Comment: Could you replace your `sudo iptables -L` listing with `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`. You aren't hitting your rules for this, so it might help to run tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) and watch for packets coming and going. Suggest: `sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp2s0 port 27960`. replace `enp2s0` with your external port name. Note: I am good with iptables but hate ufw.

Comment: How do I get my external port name?

Comment: Your edit is incomplete, and somehow has some tremendous gap in the width in the middle. If you don;t know your interface name, then just leave it out.

Comment: It's 10k characters more than StackExchange will allow sorry so I just pasted the parts that actually had port numbers on it. Is that what you were referring to? This is what I got running tcpdump: `sudo tcpdump -n -tttt port 27960
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`

Comment: do: `ip addr` and look at interface names and is ens3 the right one? I assume your box is direct connected to internet? If not, then is port 27960 forwarded properly from your router? Did tcpdump show packets arriving at your box? If the listing is too big, then use a secondary service and post it there, say the [Ubuntu one](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for example.

Comment: ip addr: `2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:00:02:ad:e9:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 207.148.86.142/23 brd 207.148.87.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 60845sec preferred_lft 60845sec
    inet6 fe80::5400:2ff:fead:e9b8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`  My box is a vultr.com VPS. Apache runs sweet so other servers are able to "broadcast" or "listen". tcpdump show nothing. I'll try post using sec service but in the meantime what do you think?

Comment: If no packets for port 27960 are even arriving at your box, then that problem needs to be solved first. (you should have at least seen my attempt to telnet a couple of minutes ago.)

Comment: I sent telnet myself and just saw the packets yes. For some reason I was able to connect this time using quake3 client, but it's not showing up in Zenmap. Odd. Thanks for your help.